# ViewFlipper FLICKERING problem?

Tags: android, drawable, viewflipper

I have a **ViewFlipper** with two **ImageView** widgets. I have set the in and out animation as **android.R.anim.slide_in_left** and **android.R.anim.slide_out_right**

Now when the two ImageViews have two different drawables, then the animation is sleek and smooth. But when I set the both the ImageViews to the same Drawable, the screen flickers. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use [`Drawable.mutate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#mutate%28%29) to prevent the drawable from being reused. :-)